# Compiling with g++ vs g++-mp

Tags: c++, macos, stl, compilation, include

I am compiling my project using g++-mp-4.9 on Mac (OS X 10.10.1) without any problem.

If I use g++, however, I get lots of errors for STL components.

g++ uses the following include folder:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/`

The standard library implementation seems to be different. for example, errors regarding the `deque`:

```
error: no template named '_Deque_iterator' in namespace
      'std'; did you mean '__deque_iterator'?
        typedef std::_Deque_iterator<LType, LType&, LType*> iterator;
                ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                     __deque_iterator
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/deque:266:29: note:
      '__deque_iterator' declared here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY __deque_iterator
```

Comment: Check with `g++ --version` command if you're not using clang in fact

Comment: That is also `g++ (MacPorts gcc49 4.9.2_1) 4.9.2`. Could it be related to the Xcode?